# Is it a good practice to put return at end of python function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have seen python functions that end without having a return. What I always do is something like this;

```
def python_function:
   # code
   return
```

There is no need to end the function with return in python. I put the return there to show clearly where the function ends. Is this a good practice in python? Are there any side effect to add this redundant return?

I am using python v3.6

Comment: There is an implicit 'return' if you do not have one in a function: It will 'return' `None` -- the same as a naked `return`

Comment: @dawg, I guess there is no side effect to put the return, correct?

Comment: No but why do you need to do this? One of the results Python's choice to make indentation significant is that it is clear where the function ends: that is, when the indentation stops.

Comment: No. From outside the function they are equivalent. The naked return at the end is redundant. `return` used as flow control is common (ie, use a naked `return` to leave a function early knowing that the return value is `None`

Comment: My view: If your function should `return` something I see nothing wrong with an explicit `return None`, but if it is a *procedural call* (like it's writing to a file) then I would definitely not add an explicit `return None`

Comment: @Chris_Rands, Which is better? `return` or `return None`? Any difference?

Comment: @user3848207 no difference